# Python combinations of list elements

Tags: python

**I have the following code:**

```
from random import randint 
Roll=[]
for i in range(3):
    zari=randint(1,6)
    Roll.append(zari)
for b in Roll:
```

the above code is deficient.
What i want my code to do is if inside the Roll list is the combination of numbers 4,5,6 to `print('Player won')`but im kinda lost
Any suggestions?

**The player wins if the combinations of the numbers is 4,5,6 and he loses if the combination is 1,2,3.This is the code that i managed to make but i cant figure out the rest of it**
**Also i forgot to mention that player wins if the combination is 2 same numbers followed by the number 6 for example 2,2,6. Any ideas on this ?** 
Thank you for every answer

Comment: Can you give some examples of win/loss conditions. Also, post what you tried that didn't work, and why.

Comment: `if all(x in Roll for x in range(4, 7)): print("Player won")`

Comment: Variable names should be lower(_case_with_underscores), hence 'Roll' should be called 'roll'. PEP-8 standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a game called [Cee-lo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cee-lo).

Check out my code:

```
from random import randint

while(True):
    Roll=[]
    for i in range(3):
        zari=randint(1,6)
        Roll.append(zari)
    if set(Roll)=={4,5,6}:
        print('Player won');   break
    elif set(Roll)=={1,2,3}:
        print('Player lose');  break
# If Roll has two same values, set() will remove duplicate value
    elif len(set(Roll))==2 and 6 in Roll:
        print('Player won',Roll);   break
    else:
        print('Rolling the dice again')
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license (2.5/3.0/4.0)](//stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3):

Try by comparing your result (Roll) with the set {4,5,6}:

```
if set(Roll)=={4,5,6}:
    print('Player won')
```

Full code:

```
from random import randint 
Roll=[]
for i in range(3):
    zari=randint(1,6)
    Roll.append(zari)
if set(Roll)=={4,5,6}:
    print('Player won')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to check at any given time if `Roll` contains 4, 5 and 6. In that case, just do this: `4 in Roll and 5 in Roll and 6 in Roll`, which will return a Boolean